# Vim Regex Replacing Addition Symbols Followed By Whitespace

Tags: regex, vim, whitespace, vi

I'm wanting to use a regex inside Vim that replaces all matches of `+ '<nonwhitespaceanychar>` with `+ '(space)`.

**NOTE** :- `(space)` means a blank space

I've tried

```
%s/\+\s'[^s]/\+\s'\s/g
```

but it fails on the plus sign. I've also tried a double backslash, but get `Misplaced +, \+ follows nothing` error.

```
Example match:
+ 'n

Example Replace
+ ' n

Example nonmatch:
+ ' n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this the below regex

```
:%s/+\s*'/+'/g
```

Comment: this will replace even if there is space after `'`. i think it was not clear before because of the bad formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups for replacement like

```
:%s/+\s'\([^ ]\)/+ ' \1/g
        <------>
    1st capturing group
```

**NOTE** :- Don't use `\s` in replacement. It will be treated as literal `\s` and not as space